# Простой FTP "сервер" на php. Какие есть решения?

Tags: php, ftp, хостинг, ftp-сервер

Есть хостинг c сервером Apache. Он не дает FTP доступа, только веб-интерфейс.
Нужна возможность подключаться через FTP.

Какие есть простые решения для этого на PHP? 
Чтоб развернуть FTP "сервер", загрузив файл с php кодом на сервер и указав в нем логин-пароль и папку для доступа.

Comment: вы думаете с помощью пхп у вас вдруг внезапно `ftp://` протокол на сервере заработает?

Comment: вероятно вы говорите не об **FTP**, а об **HTTP** сервере, который позволяет получить доступ к файлам на сервер используя простой браузер. я прав?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman судя по тому, что вэб-интерфейс для ФТП автора чем то не устроил, то вряд ли :)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman , да это тоже решение вопроса если по другому не получиться.

Comment: @teran, "внезапно ftp:// протокол на сервере заработает" - была такая надежда :) Т.е. такое в даже теоретически невозможно? Что стоит погуглить чтобы разобраться в этом вопросе?